# How can i change activeMQ persistence adapter without data loss?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I need to change activemq persistence adapter from AMQ to KahaDB, but it's not acceptable to loose all undelivered messages stored via AMQAdapter. Is there any way to automatically use old adapter to send undelivered messages and then switch to KahaDB store?

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to this is to create a new Broker instance and network the old broker and the new one.  Once the brokers are networked you create a consumer on the new broker for the destinations and allow the demand to drain the mesasge's from old to new Broker.

Refer to this [thread](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Move-from-ActiveMq-Message-Store-to-KahaDB-td2367014.html) for more: